# Delete element of array type pointer cause error?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have an example:

```
int* arr = new int[1];
//First Time
arr[0] = 5;
cout << &arr[0] << " " << arr[0] << endl;
delete &arr[0];
cout << &arr[0] << " " << arr[0] << endl;

//Second time
arr[0] = 5;
cout << &arr[0] << " " << arr[0] << endl;
delete &arr[0]; //Error from here
cout << &arr[0] << " " << arr[0] << endl;
```

The result from the code above:

```
00529EF0 5
00529EF0 -572662307
00529EF0 5
//Where the code stop
```

I don't know why it causes me the error? It doesn't let me delete `arr[0]` the second time, even though the first time successfully deleted and I assign a new value for it.

Comment: Just because it looks like the first `delete` worked, doesn't mean it did.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You `delete` something and then proceed as if that something is still valid. Basic recipe for things blowing up. I think it's on you to explain why you think this should work. (Forget the second deletion; why should something of the form `delete &X;` followed by `X = 5;` ever work?)

Answer (score 4):

If you dynamically allocate an array with `new[]`, you have to delete it with `delete[]`, which will free the entire array. You can't free individual elements. Your code has undefined behavior because you used `delete` instead of `delete[]`, so anything can happen. Just because it appeared to work doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). There is likely nothing in programming that is more fearsome.

Answer (score 1):

**Undefined Behavior**.

`&arr[0]` is the same memory address that `arr` *decays* to.  So you are really calling `delete arr;`.  This is *undefined behavior* because you are using `delete` when you need to use `delete[]` instead.  Memory allocated with `new` *MUST* be freed with `delete`.  Memory allocated with `new[]` *MUST* be freed with `delete[]`.

But, lets *assume* your compiler's runtime has enough info in the allocated array's metadata to free the array correctly.  `delete`'ing an array free the entire array.  You can't free individual elements of the array.  And accessing *any* element of of array after freeing the entire array is *undefined behavior*.  You are accessing `arr[0]` after calling `delete arr;` to free the array.  You are not allocating a new array for `arr` to point at.  You are lucky your code did not just crash outright.

That is the definition of *undefined behavior* - *ANYTHING* could happen.  You might read the old memory before it is overwritten.  You could read from random memory.  You could corrupt memory.  You could crash.